# Symfony 6 - Generate URL with "https" on twig templates

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I want to generate URL with `https://` as a prefix, using the Twig function `url()`. However, the generated URL is always `http://`.

I made the setup given here: https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/routing.html#forcing-https-on-generated-urls.

My `config/packages/framework.yaml`:

```yaml
framework:                                                                                                                                                                             
    http_method_override: false                                                                             
    handle_all_throwables: true                                                                             
    ...
```

My `config/routes.yaml`:

```yaml
controllers:                                         
    resource:                                        
        path: ../src/Controller/                     
        namespace: App\Controller                    
    type: attribute                                  
    defaults: [https] // note HTTPS here
```

I am using the PROD environment.

My `.env` file is:

```
APP_ENV=prod
APP_URL=https://something... // note HTTPS here
```

Cache has been cleared with prod option.

However, when I use from my twig template:

```
{{ url('my_route') }}
```

the generated route is correct but still in `http` (and not `https`).

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Using `{{ absolute_url(path('my_route')) }}` fixed it. My link is rendered with the scheme `https://`.

Thanks all for your replies. I guess the fix I made from Arleigh Hix suggestion was also part of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Looking here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#forcing-https-on-generated-urls you will see you missed the `schemes` key in your config. Here is the example given:

```yaml
# config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    defaults:
        schemes: [https]
```

Or do the following on a per route basis:

```php
    #[Route('/login', name: 'login', schemes: ['https'])]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have just tried the exact solution you mentioned above for the yaml file; (in `config/routes.yaml` in my case) but still, the URL generated into the twig template with `{{ url('my_route', {'id': ...}, true ) }}` (from here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#url) still has `http://` prefix.

In fact, the content generated with that twig template is then sent by email and I now realize by checking the mail content "in HTML format" that there is no scheme at all in the generated URL (I have something like: `//my-domain.com/my-route`)

Comment: I guess the "http://" prefix is added automatically by the mail client, as there is no scheme in the URL. I am going to try the twig function `absolute_url` or the second solution you suggest that adds the scheme on a per route basis.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web server (ngnix, apache, etc) configuration, it was using the port `80` internally

There a trick to test: comment out the `listen 80`, if your site is unavailable that means it uses the port `80`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed this is something to think about, especially when the final web server is behind a gateway, a proxy or a load balancer. Very often, the frontend proxy listens on HTTPS and then forward traffic to the final web server using HTTP only, because routing is made internally into a private isolated network behind that proxy. That was not my issue here, but that is something to consider when dealing with that kind of issue.