Symfony 7 - LoginLinkHandler - Forcing HTTPS prefix
I generate an OTP link using the following function:
$loginLinkDetails = $this->loginLinkHandler->createLoginLink();
$loginLink = $loginLinkDetails->getUrl();                              

The generated login link is always prefixed by http:// and not https://, even if my whole application is running on https.
I have tried to configure the scheme of generated URLs as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76648584/3146662 without success.
Note that my variables (in .env.prod) APP_URL and BASE_URL both contains the https prefix.
How can I generate my OTP link with https// prefix ?
